# What is wrong with this flower?

Tags: flowers

[image]

Today morning I was surprised to see this flower as it has four normal pale orange coloured petals and one bright red one. This is a flower of Hibiscus and all the flowers of this plant have the normal pale orange coloured petals, while this one has a bright red one.

What can cause this?

Comment: Maybe just a rare mutation?

Comment: Then why should only one flower show it? If it was a rare mutation I guess all the flowers would have one red petal. But this plant gives the same coloured flowers everyday.

Comment: Maybe an insect or fungus that affected the bud?

Comment: Could be a rare mutation next to the flower which only affects the flower... maybe sth which was induced... mutations do not necessarily have to occur in seed state etc.